# Is there a way to write the errors given in corner plots

Tags: python, plot

I have made a corner plot which gives me the values of 3 parameters and their errors.

Is there a way to use these upper and lower errors which are given in corner plots and to put these values in an array or write these values in a file?

[image: corner plot]

I am searching for something like:

```
x = corner.quantile(parameter value) 
dx_up = corner.quantile(upper error)
dx_low = corner.quantile(lower error)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have plotted the data calling:

```
fig = corner.corner(samples,show_titles=True,...)
```

These values can be retrieved with the following code:

```
for i in range(2): # must be done once per variable
    q_16, q_50, q_84 = corner.quantile(samples[:,i], [0.16, 0.5, 0.84]) # your x is q_50
    dx_down, dx_up = q_50-q_16, q_84-q_50
    # save and/or print them
```

These will be the exact same values shown in the title (if rounded to the 2nd decimal place) because I have checked the [corner.py source code for titles](https://github.com/dfm/corner.py/blob/master/corner/corner.py#L277)

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. Thanks